# How can I detect the enviroment in office 365?

Tags: office365, office-js

I have a outlook add-in with javascript api and from my website I want to redirect to the correct enviroment for the app,

```
var isSetSupported = function(Application, version) {
                return window["Office"] && Office.context.requirements && Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported(Application + 'Api', version);
            };

            //heck to return the powerpoint library because isSetSupported returns false for PowerpointApi 1.0| 1.1| 1.2 returns false
            var isPowerpointEnviroment = function() {
                return window.location.search.indexOf('_host_Info=Powerpoint') != -1;
            }

            //heck to return the outlook library because isSetSupported returns false for OutlookApi 1.0| 1.1| 1.2 returns false
            var isOutlookEnviroment = function () {
                return window.location.search.indexOf('_host_Info=Outlook') != -1 || ( window.external &&  window.external.GetContext && typeof window.external.GetContext() == 'object');
            }

            if (isSetSupported("Word", 1.1)) {
                return "wordJs";
            }
            if (isSetSupported("Excel", 1.1)) {
                return "excelJs";
            }
            if (isOutlookEnviroment()) {
                return "outlookJs";
            }
            if (isPowerpointEnviroment()) {
                return "powerpointJs";
            }

            return "webApp";
```

on the outlook from local machine it works like this but for office365 outlook it doesn't work.

Comment: we are evaluating adding an API to detect host ("Excel, Word, Outlook, etc) & platform (Desktop, Mac, Web, etc) info. To make sure we're taking it into account, would you mind describing the particular use-cases you are facing, that led you to seek this API? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What is "Office.context.requirements"? What does it return? It's not even listed in the API reference as a property/object of Office.context: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161104.aspx.

Regardless, for Outlook you need to access the Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics object, and read the hostname and hostVersion propreties: https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.html